# Spectrogram of a shock event

Tags: algorithms, spectrogram, stft

I have measured data of a vibration with chirp input were I suspect unwanted shock events occurred.
I therefore thought about computing the spectrogram of my time histories to check the frequency content.

I am however not fully sure about what to look for. My idea would be to look for a straight line at a given step in time across all frequencies (because a shock event, like two bodies hitting each other, is normally short in time and excites all frequencies). Is that correct?

Are there other ways to detect shock occurrence?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, have you tried it? What did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as spectrograms go, you're correct. Worth noting, as shocks are time-localized, higher time resolution windows (in Heisenberg sense, meaning narrower in time) are preferred, and so is lower `hop_size` - otherwise spikes may be show as lower in intensity or be missed entirely.

Comparison on signal with four "shocks" (-- [messy code](https://pastebin.com/R0MgWBfV)):

[image]